# Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope - Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob, cocoapods

I am a beginner in Xcode, and I have just installed the Firebase framework with CocoaPods. When I import the framework, I want to add the line "FirebaseApp.configure()" but when I add it, Xcode gives me an error : "Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope". How can I solve this error?
I already tried to re-install the framework !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au7V8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have opened the wrong project. Things you can do to verify is to

1. Check if the pods have been added. For this check the root directory in `Finder` and see if you have a folder called `Pods`, or check if a folder named `Pods` can be seen in your project within XCode. If not open terminal go to your project directory and type `pod install`
2. After you have verified that the pods have been installed, open the `KeKonMange.xcworkspace` instead of the `KeKonMange.xcodeproj` from your finder directory (`.xcworkspace` is the **white** icon, while `.xcodeproj` is the **blue** one. example can be found below)

If you can't resolve your problem, comment below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already opened the .xcworkspace file. So I checked if the Pods were installed and they are in the Pods folder. The error is still present... How to solve it?

Comment: try **closing xcode -> removing Pods directory -> removing xcworkspace directory -> launch pod install again -> open KeKonMange.xcworkspace**

Comment: When I type the order, I get warnings that are [the following...](https://i.imgur.com/L3UwSTO.png)
Otherwise, I still have the same problem but I tried to launch the project and a new error appeared: "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'". I think it must be related...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but when I tried to launch the project, another error appeared: "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'"... Maybe it has something to do with...?

Image of code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgkSz.png